# How can we append list in a subsequent manner in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.newegg.com/CPUs-Processors/Category/ID-34'
r = requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')

processor_price = []
prices = soup.find_all('li', {"class": "price-current"})
for price in prices:
    processor_price.append(price.text.split())
print(processor_price)
```

I am getting this output:

```
[['$414.99', '(24', 'Offers)–'], ['$709.99', '(12', 'Offers)–'], ['$319.99', '(34', 'Offers)–'], ['$439.99', '(12', 'Offers)–'], ['$199.99', '(31', 'Offers)–'], ['$71.87', '(26', 'Offers)–'], 
['$289.99', '(15', 'Offers)–'], ['$164.99', '(28', 'Offers)–'], ['$214.99', '(16', 'Offers)–'], ['$304.99', '(20', 'Offers)–'], ['$199.99', '(13', 'Offers)–']]
```

I need this output:

```
['$414.99','$709.99','$319.99','$439.99'...]
```

Comment: ``processor_price.append(price.text.split()[0])`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output that you got is a list in which the value you want is in the first index and so.

```
processor_price.append(price.text.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this additional processing.

```
for price_array in processor_price:
  print(price_array[0])
```

This will let you parse the first element of every list. You can then package this to a separate list.

```
final_list = []
for price_array in processor_price:
  final_list.append(price_array[0])
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending to the list:

```
processor_price.append(price.text.split()[0])
```

or printing the first index value from the existing list using list comprehension:

```
print([pr[0] for pr in processor_price])
```